# Z-index not working divs are side by side not on top

Tags: css, z-index

I am working on a layout and i have to divs they are showing as side by side instead of one on top of the other, navbox should sit above right-side.  I have set the z-index for navbox but makes no difference.

I have made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JGesg/

here is the css for the divs,

```
#navbox
{
    background: red;
    width:70px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:50;
    top:0;
    float:right;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}


#right-side{
    top:5%;
    width:20%;
    height:90%;
    float:right;
    padding:0.2%;
    background-color: green;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: z-index will do nothing other than change which one is on top, you want to use `position:` to style these on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Place the div `#navbox` inside the div `#right-side`

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<div id ="right-side">
     <div id="navbox"><hr><hr><hr>
     </div>
</div>
```

you have problems because you don't declarate the `position` and the `px` for numbers of positions

```
#navbox
{
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    width:70px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:50;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}


#right-side{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width:20%;
    height:90%;
    float:right;
    padding:0.2%;
    background-color: green;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

i hope this can help you